# Python: Function Documentation

Tags: python

Is there a way to check what a function or a method does inside of python itself similar to the help function in Matlab. I want to get the definition of the function without having to Google it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can call `help(whatever)` inside python interactive interpreter.

```
>>> help
Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.

>>> help(zip)
Help on built-in function zip in module __builtin__:

zip(...)
    zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

    Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
    from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
    in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

You can even pass (quoted) keywords and get very detailed help:

```
>>> help('if')
The ``if`` statement
********************

The ``if`` statement is used for conditional execution:

   if_stmt ::= "if" expression ":" suite
               ( "elif" expression ":" suite )*
               ["else" ":" suite]

It selects exactly one of the suites by evaluating the expressions one
by one until one is found to be true (see section *Boolean operations*
for the definition of true and false); then that suite is executed
(and no other part of the ``if`` statement is executed or evaluated).
If all expressions are false, the suite of the ``else`` clause, if
present, is executed.

Related help topics: TRUTHVALUE

>>> help('def')
Function definitions
********************

A function definition defines a user-defined function object
....
```

Or even general topics:

```
>>> help('FUNCTIONS')
Functions
*********

Function objects are created by function definitions.  The only
operation on a function object is to call it: ``func(argument-list)``.

There are really two flavors of function objects: built-in functions
and user-defined functions.  Both support the same operation (to call
the function), but the implementation is different, hence the
different object types.

See *Function definitions* for more information.

Related help topics: def, TYPES
```

---

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help

> Invoke the built-in help system. (This function is intended for interactive use.) If no argument is given, the interactive help system starts on the interpreter console.
>
> If the argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and a help page is printed on the console.
>
> If the argument is any other kind of object, a help page on the object is generated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough answer. The string thing was pretty helpful, not sure why I haven't tried it exactly.
Also after playing around I found that you have to type `help('module.method')` to get the help for the methods, so for sqrt `help('math.sqrt')` and for append it's `help('list.append')`

Answer (score 1):

The help() function gives you help on almost everything but if your searching for something (like a module to use) then type help('modules') and it will search for available modules.

Then if you need to find information about a module load it and type dir(module_name) to see the methods that are defined in the module.

Comment: It is kind of amazing that I am through 150 pages of a python book and it has never mentioned dir() or help(). Thanks!!